# Reloading div containing Youtube Iframe player API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I'm trying to get document reloaded every 10 seconds when onStateChange has value YT.PlayerState.ENDED (0) or YT.PlayerState.CUED (5).

Document IS NOT meant to be reloaded if YT.PlayerState is something else than YT.PlayerState.ENDED (0) or YT.PlayerState.CUED (5).

The problem is that document gets reloaded even when YT.PlayerState is NOT ENDED (0) or CUED (5).

The code below displays random Metallica video from Youtube from the following list:

- Metallica - Until it sleeps (Youtube video ID = F3WIHtOmkBg)
- Metallica - The unforgiven (Youtube video ID = TUHFfR8hWcA)
- Metallica - Nothing else matters (Youtube video ID = Tj75Arhq5ho)

I have found out that YT.PlayerState.PLAYING (1) is firing and 'Playing' gets logged to the console but it seems that "clearTimeout()" and "refresh = undefined" has no effect and thus document will be reloaded even when video is playing (has status YT.PlayerState.PLAYING (1)).

I have used [YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) as a reference.

At the moment my code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Youtube, F3WIHtOmkBg - Metallica - Until it sleeps
// Youtube, TUHFfR8hWcA - Metallica - The unforgiven
// Youtube, Tj75Arhq5ho - Metallica - Nothing else matters

var videoArray = [
    'F3WIHtOmkBg',
    'TUHFfR8hWcA',
    'Tj75Arhq5ho'];

var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * videoArray.length);
var randomVideoId = videoArray[randomIndex];

var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

function refresh() { setTimeout(function() {

    window.location = window.location.pathname;

    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        width: '550',
        height: '331',
        videoId: randomVideoId,
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });

}, 10000);
}

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        width: '550',
        height: '331',
        videoId: randomVideoId,
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.stopVideo();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        refresh();
    console.log('Ended');
    }

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        clearTimeout();
        refresh = undefined;
    console.log('Playing');
    }

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
        clearTimeout();
        refresh = undefined;
    console.log('Paused');
    }

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
        clearTimeout();
        refresh = undefined;
    console.log('Buffering');
    }

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.CUED) {
        refresh();
    console.log('Cued');
    }

}

function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
}
</script>
</head>
<boby>
<div id="youtubetest">
    <div id="player"></div>
</div>
<div id="currenttime">
<script>
var now = new Date();
var datetime = now.getFullYear()+'/'+(now.getMonth()+1)+'/'+now.getDate();
datetime += ' '+now.getHours()+':'+now.getMinutes()+':'+now.getSeconds();
document.write('Current time is: ' + now);
</script>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: and when you place a console.log('yo!') right before the clearInterval it´s beeing logged ? And what is myTimer() ?

Comment: Neverming myTimer(). It was just some of my earlier testing. I added new improved code with console.logging on the opening post.